# Opening SQLite database for Windows 8.1 in Phonegap Desktop

Tags: windows, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to build my first Phonegap application using SQLite for storage. The app will be storing simples notes in phone(Not that complex). I have tested the app in iPhone using Phonegap Developer app and it works fine. but on my Windows 8.1 device, it is not working well. I can confirm that opening database is not working. Here is my code for opening the database.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() 
    {   
        var phone = device.platform;

        if(phone=="Android")
        {
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "DatabaseName"});
            db.transaction(CreateLogin, errorDB, successDB);
        }
        else
        {
            db = window.openDatabase("DatabaseName", "1.0", "Database Desc", 200000);
            alert("Database Created");
            db.transaction(CreateLogin, errorDB, successDB);    
        }
    }
    </script>
```

When testing in iPhone, I have received 'Database Created' message and everything works too. But on Windows, it doesn't work. I have alerted the device platform name and it shows Win32NT. Am I doing it right? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation of the openDatabase method](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.7.0/cordova/storage/storage.opendatabase.html), the supported platforms are :

> Android
>
> BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 6.0 and higher)
>
> iPhone

So it won't work on Windows.

I would recommend looking at the [newer options for storing data in a Cordova app.](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/storage/storage.html)

Comment: Thanks buddy! The link helped me. Also I have noticed that I was using just WebSQL in my code. I am going to use SQLite from https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#readme